# What to look in a truly dishwasher friendly non-stick cookware?

Tags: non-stick, dishwasher

Dishwasher + Non-stick = Disaster. I know that, but still I'm wondering what type of non-stick cookware I can buy which would be more resilient towards dishwasher?

I know ideally you don't want to put your non-stick cookware in dishwasher but let's say if I choose to do so, what sort of non-stick cookware would last longer?

Are there certain non-stick technologies that are more dishwasher "friendly"? Would choosing steel over aluminum help longevity of the cookware considering daily dishwasher wash?

### ----/ Update 1 /----

Just to show why I'm looking for a more durable nonstick solution, here is the [Heritage Rock Nonstick pot](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/heritage-the-rock-forged-non-stick-cookware-set-dishwasher-oven-safe-black-10-pc-1427071p.1427071.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA3rKQBhCNARIsACUEW_YD0n3uw5CJEKDUXscFoROTflkAQHNnlgJ__AVTwvLJ-OyTKs4U2JAaAokxEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#store=609) I used and washed in dishwasher everyday for 6 months.

[image: Heritage Rock pot]
Heritage Rock pot

[image: Nonstick is gone]
Nonstick is gone!

[image: Rim is destoyed]
Rim is destroyed

[image: Nonstick is peeling]
Nonstick is peeling

[image: Compare to less used one from the same set]
Compare to less used one from the same set

[image: How the nonstick used to look like]
How nonstick used to look like

### ----/ Update 3 /----

In case anyone is interested, [Starfrit](https://www.starfrit.com/en/about-us) (the company behind the Heritage Rock brand) **did decline my warranty claim** on the basis of *incorrect use*.

They mention high temperature and metal utensils. I have induction stove so there is no direct heat, and the generated heat at the base of the pot should be very balanced. Also I mostly made rice which you don't use high heat for. I never use metal utensils on nonstick. It is the dishwasher that killed it and they don't want to admit that.

Anyways, I think this is how most of warranty claims end up. I think a $20 pot from Ikea would do better than my pot in 6 months :D

Comment: Actually, your last picture is not "how nonstick used to look like". If you look carefully, you will see that the coating is worn off on the highest "hills" of the surface. These are the places where the detergent seeps between coating and pan and attacks the bond between the two, as well as the exposed aluminum surface. This is not about the pan brand, it is about how you use the pans - it looks as if you are using metal utensils on them or abrading them in other ways. Also, if I were to wash nonstick in the dw, I would use a mild cycle, certainly not the heavy wash.

Comment: I only use nonmetal on my nonstick cookware. But I do wash them in dishwasher on heavy duty cycle with tablet. I did know that this is not the best way to treat nonstick but I didn't think it would get damaged in 6 months so badly! If it could last even 2 years that would be good for me. Basically I'm just looking for a nonstick pot that can only take more dishwasher abuse. It doesn't need to be metal utensils resistant.

Comment: I left an answer. But here for short: It is not about the pot being metal utensil resistant (no nonstick pan is truly resistant to that), it is that using a metal utensil makes the dishwasher damage come sooner. I have no idea if you can get 2 years out of a nonstick pan with daily dishwasher use even if everything else is perfect, but you can try.

Comment: The issue is as much the dishwasher as it is the pan— dishwasher detergent has some grit in it to help scour as it sprays onto the pans, so it’s like using a scrub brush.  It might be that there are ones out there specifically for cleaning nonstick pans (but would do a poor job on stuck-on foods and the other things detergents advertise as doing well)

Comment: After your added info - I have a [ScanPan Pro IQ 12.5" frying pan](https://www.scanpan.com/pro-iq-12-5-inch-fry-pan-46170-configurable). It's too soon to know how long it will last, only had it a year, but it's doing very well so far. I wouldn't *dream* of ever putting it in the dishwasher at that price. It takes *seconds* to clean under the tap.

Comment: Sorry, I had to rollback. We have a rule that we don't do shopping recommendations for concrete brands or producers. We can list criteria, as your original version of the question asks for, but you have to use other sources to decide which product fits them well enough.

Comment: @RedSonja does my stackoverflow profile look like an advertiser to you?! I'm just trying to figure out if there is solution for nonstick + dishwasher.

Comment: @Joe I agree. I think the main issue is the abrasive detergent. But if you don't use one most probably dishwasher cannot do a good job and you'd be better off washing by hand.

Comment: @unlisted3 I was thinking the same thing. If I buy an expensive pot, I will not end up putting it in a dishwasher. So I guess I have to aim for midrange cookware.

Comment: @rumtscho I understand. Fair enough. My intention was to get feedback on whether that brand model fits the criteria we were discussing or not.

Comment: @kaptan I think it might be worth asking a new question on how to clean non-stick pans, as we have a similar one for cast iron, and there are much different considerations for either of those vs. stainless cookware.  (I know o ruined someone’s non-stick decades ago, as I tried to scrub stuff that had gotten stuck; I probably should’ve let it soak or something)

Comment: @Joe haha... : ))  Believe it or not, I do know how to wash a nonstick gently by hand. It is just the sheer amount of other chores I have to do, that I would rather leave washing nonstick to dishwasher  :D

Answer (score 4):

Look for one with a ten-year guarantee that states specifically is is dishwasher-friendly.

Keep the receipt.

There is a general rule that the more you pay, the longer it will last, but even just cooking in it if you can get more than a couple of years' useful life out of a frying pan without it getting sticky, you're doing well. Maybe 5 on the expensive stuff.

Personally, I wouldn't dream of putting my non-stick pans in the dishwasher. You can just about rinse them in hot water if they're good.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. I cannot find any brand that specifically say it is really ok to put their non-stick cookware in dishwasher. They always say "dishwasher safe" but then say that it is better if you just wash it by hand. I haven't found a brand that claims their non-stick cookware is really dishwasher friendly.

Comment: Agreed. Besides, if it's really non-stick, it should be really easy to hand-wash.

Comment: I just read your profile... did I miss something?

Comment: Rinse in water directly after cooking. That is the point of non-stick, that's why we buy it.

Comment: @AnastasiaZendaya - long story.

Comment: @unlisted I see. Well, good luck! I I just thought I might be able to relate, given what I've been through in one particular Stack Exchange site in the past :)

Answer (score 4):

*Would choosing steel over aluminum help longevity of the cookware considering daily dishwasher wash?*

Not in my experience.

I use my dishwasher for essentially all my washing up but I am careful to  load it so that things can't rub against the inside of the pans.

I've got a set of 3 non-stick aluminium saucepans bought several (at least 5) years ago which are as good as new.   They go through the dishwasher every few days, and are stored stacked inside each other.  I got them at sale price, and they were the best of a stores own brand (I thought they were discontinued but some sizes [are still available](https://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/brand/linea/excellence-saucepan-799696#colcode=79969603)).  A lot of their use is frying or sweating, then adding wet ingredients to build a dish; for pure boiling tasks I tend to use my stainless pans where possible to save the non-stick for when it's needed.

My frying pans are one sandwich-base steel (probably ikea), one large aluminium (ikea), and one small aluminium (supermarket own brand), all at least 10 years old.  The two smaller ones are now getting a bit sticky in places but still pretty decent; the larger is used less.

So moderately-priced steel and aluminium non-stick has been about the same for me.

Comment: Tnx for sharing your experience. If you don't mind could you share the brand and models that lasted you 5 years? I bough a [Heritage Rock Non-Stick Set](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/heritage-the-rock-forged-non-stick-cookware-set-dishwasher-oven-safe-black-10-pc-1427071p.1427071.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiA3rKQBhCNARIsACUEW_aSoZXmjTpidbcCxg4xVxFZeOpTFFZM3FSdWtmPLR8eb2VEeSw6wqMaAs9eEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#store=608). Cooking in the pot and washing it in dishwasher (with tablet + heavy wash) daily, only lasted 6 months. I will post a picture later of how damaged the non-stick coating and the body is.

Comment: @kaptan the ones I bought are discontinued and were only sold in the UK under that name anyway.  Everything I can remember is in the answer already.  In the dishwasher I use either Finish brand tablets (when they're on offer) or supermarket own brand but not the really cheap ones because they don't get things clean.  And the 50°C eco program

Comment: Having seen your pictures, I reckon all of mine were made  a bit smoother than yours. The rim is the biggest issue, but on my set the non-stick coating goes down the outside of the sides as well, so the edge of the coating is at the bottom edge of the pan, not the more vulnerable top

Comment: I think smoother nonstick probably can make a more durable finish because water and soap has less chance to get under it as @rumtscho mentioned. I also agree that the rim is very vulnerable but apparently manufacturers don't put much effort into building a durable one.

Comment: @kaptan they do still exist, or very similar.  I remembered to look at the branding and I've added a link

Answer (score 2):

My parents wash all their pans in the dishwasher. They haven't seen as much use as yours, but I am still surprised at how well they hold up. I cannot see much problems in their coatings. Sure, they are somewhat burnt and so less non-stick, but that's because of improper use of heat, not because of the dishwasher.

From what I have seen in their pans, and from your pictures, I would suggest that you can do the following:

- Choose ceramic-coated pans, rather than PTFE-coated ones.
- Look for pans with a very even finish, especially if they are PTFE. You can see in the photo that the hills-and-valleys surface on your current pans is working against you.
- I would probably recommend aluminum over steel, even though it doesn't seem to make a difference for Chris H and for my parents. It is obvious that your damage includes a lot of peeling, and the aluminum at the edges of the peeled areas is corroded by the detergent, which worsens the peeling. With bare (non SS) steel, the corrosion in these places will be rust, which is crumblier than corroded aluminum.
- A lot of your peeling has started on the rim of the pans. Try getting pans which are only nonstick-coated on the inside, and have enamel or something else on the outside. Bare stainless steel is good - it should also be better than aluminum wrt last point. You will have less damagable surface that way, and the rim is also highly endangered because of rubbing with lids.
- Since there was a version mentioning a brand: if a brand states that their pan is dishwasher-friendly, it is a good sign. Sure, it may be a lie (a lot of the claims surrounding nonstick pans are a lie, or at least exaggerated), but it improves your chances of getting more use out of the pan.
- Not shopping advice, but make sure you handle your pans with utmost care. Sometimes people do get away with using metal on theirs, or overheating them, but as you see in your case, the combination of scratches or heat-degraded coating and dishwasher detergent really damages the pan. You should gently use soft (wood or plastic) utensils on them, use them only for low-temperature cooking, and protect them while stacking (if you don't want to buy felt protectors, a piece of kitchen paper works).
  In the meantime, you mentioned that you don't use metal. Nevertheless, it is clearly visible that some of the coating was abraded in the newer pan, and it happened by rubbing against a flat surface (or against a wide edge, such as a spatula edge) and not by scouring dust in the detergent. If you are doing any rubbing with anything harder than wood, stop it.
- Again a part of maintenance: never expose your pans to thermal shock. Heat them slowly, with food already in them, and once hot, don't add cold (or room temperature) liquids to them.
- And lastly, get used to the idea that nonstick pans are an item with a limited timespan. If you use a nonstick pan everyday, you need both luck and perfect care for it to last maybe 3-5 years. With a dishwasher, its lifetime will certainly be shorter.

Comment: Tnx a lot for the tips. I do think as well as you said that I need to choose a nostick with a smooth finish. But I still think stainless steel will hold better in dishwasher though. None of my SS cookware is damaged in dishwasher. Very good point on ceramic coating. Thaty a good idea. I do agree with all of your tips and honestly other than using the dishwasher I do not abuse my cookware. I just believe we should push the industry to build better quality nonstick that are truly dishwasher safe and more sustainable. I do believe nanotech has lots to offer in this field.

Comment: +1 on the ceramic pans. Of all non-stick I've had the ceramic coated ones are the sturdiest, and they did survive a bunch of dishwasher cycles (I started washing them by hand when the aluminium outside started to get damaged)